# CSS scaling and centering a page

Tags: javascript, css, document-body

Why does this work in `Firefox`, but not in `Chrome`:

```
position:absolute; 
overflow: hidden; 
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
transform: translate(240px,79.5px) scale(1.2484375);
```

In `translate(x,y)` and `scale(value), x,y,` and value are different for different computers/browsers.

it works for Firefox, but Chrome, does not get **scaled** or **translated**.

demo:
**
http://jsfiddle.net/SergioAntonio/kp9yr4m1/

## **

its seems like I found a solution:
I changed the JavaScript code from:
**document.body.style="transform: translate(240px,79.5px) scale(1.2484375)";**

to

**document.body.style.transform="translate(240px,79.5px) scale(1.2484375)";**

and now it works in chrome.

Comment: Your styles are fine, it should work. I guess there is something else that you didn't post. Your best bet is to create a demo replicating the issue.

Comment: I agree with dfsq. This fiddle show it working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/azzce5zk/

Comment: ok, I added a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SergioAntonio/kp9yr4m1/
works for FF, does nothing for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried vendor-prefixing it properly?

```
-webkit-transform: translate(240px,79.5px) scale(1.2484375);
```

Chrome started natively offering support for transform only in Version 36. For older versions, also for most Android browsers, you will still have to prefix it.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
.example {
  -webkit-transform: translate(240px,79.5px) scale(1.2484375);
      -ms-transform: translate(240px,79.5px) scale(1.2484375);
          transform: translate(240px,79.5px) scale(1.2484375);
}
```